# Support for Wireless Network Interface PCI Cards as of now?

Tags: wireless

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop.I use my smartphone as a wifi hotspot in case my Wired Broadband goes down or becomes unusable, So i thought of buying a usb wifi adapter and bought a TENDA TE­W311MI Wireless N150 USB Adapter Nano from Amazon since it was the only one that said will support Linux OS and it did But after a few days it died,I have heard such instances with USB Adapter are a common thing,So i am thinking of getting a PCI Card for this,But i am not sure which of those supports Linux,So please guide me in this search with your knowledge and i prefer a card in the budget range.
Thank you.
Rahul

Comment: Read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and this network adapter, worked just fine since I bough it. Alfa Network AWUS036NHA 5 DBi - Adaptador